# How to create a table inside a table cell in reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am in a situation where I need to create a table inside the table cell, which is the description field in the data which will be a list itself. I need to make a table out of that list.
Below is the code that I am currently using to create a normal table in reportlab, I just need to insert a table inside a table in the description field of this table, the description field itself would be a list inside the data list.

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A1
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate, Frame, PageTemplate, Paragraph, Table, TableStyle
from functools import partial
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus.doctemplate import SimpleDocTemplate

cm = 2.58
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

data = [["Register","S.No.", "PON","Description","Quantity","Cost","Supplier","DOR","RVN","Alloted Lab",
"TON","TOD","Transferred Dept./Lab","Remarks"],
    ["Register REG1", 12, 56, Paragraph('Here is large field retrieve from database Here is large field retrieve from database Here is large field retrieve from database', styles['Normal']), 4,"4466561", "SHAKTI", "2021-09-05", 778, "Iron Man Lab", 4566, "2021-09-04", "Tony Stark Lab", "This is the remark for REG1"]]

for i in range(0,6):
    data.extend(data)

doc = SimpleDocTemplate('testtable.pdf', pagesize=A1)

table = Table(data, repeatRows=1)

# add style

numberofcols = len(data[0])


style = TableStyle([
    ('BACKGROUND', (0,0), (numberofcols,0), colors.green),
    ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(-1,0),colors.whitesmoke),
    ('ALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
    ('FONTNAME', (0,0), (-1,0), 'Courier-Bold'),
    ('FONTSIZE', (0,0), (-1,0), 14),
    ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0,0), (-1,0), 12),
    ('BACKGROUND',(0,1),(-1,-1),colors.beige),
])
table.setStyle(style)

# 2) Alternate backgroud color -- formatting
rowNumb = len(data)
for i in range(1, rowNumb):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        bc = colors.burlywood
    else:
        bc = colors.beige
    
    ts = TableStyle(
        [('BACKGROUND', (0,i),(-1,i), bc)]
    )
    table.setStyle(ts)

# 3) Add borders -- formatting 
ts = TableStyle(
    [
    ('BOX',(0,0),(-1,-1),2,colors.black),
    ('LINEBEFORE',(2,1),(2,-1),2,colors.red),
    ('LINEABOVE',(0,2),(-1,2),2,colors.green),
    ('GRID',(0,1),(-1,-1),2,colors.black),
    ]
)
table.setStyle(ts)

elems = []

# elems.append("TABLE TITLE")
elems.append(table)

doc.build(elems)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this case, reportlab's documentation doesn't help how to achieve this. My answer is heavily based in this comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658565/auto-size-nested-table-height-rows-with-reportlab). To create a Table inside a row you have to first create a new table and add them to your "original table". Bellow I will explain the steps:

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, TableStyle, Table

# Creating a simple pdfdoc = SimpleDocTemplate(aa)
story = []

# Set a table style
table_style = TableStyle(
    [
        ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
        ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ]
)

# Creating mock data and cols to add a new table inside the third a row
data_table = [
    ['Col1', 'Col2'], 
    ['aaa', 'bbb'],
    [Table([['data to add as third row', 'a']], style=table_style)]
]


final_table = Table(data_table, style=table_style)
story.append(final_table)
doc.build(story)
```

Comment: Did you happen to come across the inline table printing as code, rather than the formatted table?